# mongo db structure for app

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm learning mongo db and the fact it's different from relational dbs raises me some questions; I'm projecting an app with, obviouvsly users.
Users have have notifications, a cart containing apps, a subscription array containing already bought apps. Also users can store their incomes in another collection and compare it with other family members.
So this is how I planned the bd

```
Users: {
    profile:{
       name,
       surname,
       ...
   },
   preferences:{
     date_format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
     lang: 'it',
     ...
   },
   cart:[ appId1, appId2...],
   subscriptions:[ appId3, appId4 ]
   family:{
       id: 12309asd
       admin: true,
       join_date: Date
   }
}

Apps: {
    _id: asd8a0asd,
    name: String,
    price:{
      monthly: 20,
      yearly:  50
    },
    i18n:{
       description: {
          it: '',
          en: ''
      }
    }
}

Incomes_categories: {
    _id: 2131sdf0s,
    name: ''
}

Incomes:{
    _id: 098asda
    user_id: 908asdasf,
    category: It'll store the category name, not the id so if someone change the name of a cateogry it'll not ruin the one stored in this collection,
    money_value: float
}
```

Could be this approach correct?

Comment: It's a good enough start, you'll find out more as you start trying to query the db. Why have a separate incomes collection instead of just putting the incomeCategoryId in the user object? Why is that crosswalk different?

Comment: If I put categories on the user obj doesn't it become very huge? Probably I'll have many other collections with categories! So, if the user object contains too much informations, the queries wouldn't be so slow then?

Comment: Correct - where you put related data depends a lot on the size of those relationships. I would assume that a user is not going to be in many income categories however so that one seems like it would be small but you understand your data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! Now I got the point a bit more!

Comment: You might find [this post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) useful as well. Good luck!